# Rails Active Storage - Copy Files from one app to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activestorage

Just a simple question (which probable isn't easy to answer) but can one copy all the Active Storage files from one app to another after cloning the postgresql database from the one app to the other?

Comment: Depends on where they are stored. If in local filesystem, it's easier, you copy copy the files under the same folder and you should be good. Cloud storage (like AWS S3) is a bit more involved, but also not impossible.

Comment: Thanks, didn't think it would be that easy @SergioTulentsev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the database (including the tables created by Active Storage) to your other application and also copy the files from the `storage` folder to the other app's storage folder.